# Ubuntu core not working on any Raspberry PI 3 B or 3B+

Tags: ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I have tried the latest stable and edge versions of the Ubuntu Core on a RPI 3 B and a RPI 3 B+. Burned the image using etcher and also following the instructions on the page (https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/raspberry-pi-2-3) on a Ubuntu 16. In all cases the same problem, the image boots, but after some time just black screen... I am a bit puzzled that the same error appears on all images and on different devices, does the current images work at all? 
I have tried on the same hardwares raspbian and dietpi, everything works flawless, so I know both the flashcard and the hardware are working.

Comment: https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/raspberry-pi-2-3

Comment: I tried four times, two with the stable and one with edge in RPI 3 B+ and one with stable in RPI 3. Same problem with all of them, it starts booting but then at some point just goes black. On the same hardware I tried ubutu mate, arch linux, diet pi and raspbian, all without any issues.

Comment: Please edit additional information into your question - comments sometimes get deleted, or are unread by folks who can help you. Comments are not intended for conversation, but to help you improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas (and no comment permissions yet):

- Disconnect any external USB storage devices *before* booting for the first time.
- Press *enter* on a USB-attached keyboard. (you've probably tried this)